# Map reduce chaining

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Data sharing in Hadoop Map Reduce chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154720/data-sharing-in-hadoop-map-reduce-chaining)

I have map reduce chain as mentioned below.

Job1(Map1 -> Reduce 1) --> Job2(Map2, Reduce2)   Job1.waitForCompletion(true)

I need a value (suppose int a ,which is created by Reduce 1) , in Map2.

How can I do this ?? Please share your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

You can use ChainMapper and ChainReducer . Here is a sample code for your help .

---

---

```
Configuration conf = getConf();
JobConf job = new JobConf(conf);
JobConf Conf1 = new JobConf(false);
ChainMapper.setMapper
(job,
Map1.class,
LongWritable.class,
Text.class,
Text.class,
Text.class,
true,
Conf1);


 JobConf Conf2 = new JobConf(false);
    ChainReducer.setReducer
    (job,
    Reduce1.class,
    Text.class,
    Text.class,
    Text.class,
    Text.class,
    true,
    Conf2);
JobConf Conf3 = new JobConf(false);
    ChainMapper.setMapper
    (job,
    Map2.class,
    Text.class,
    Text.class,
    Text.class,
    Text.class,
    true,
    Conf3);
JobConf Conf4 = new JobConf(false);
    ChainReducer.setReducer
    (job,
    Reduce2.class,
    Text.class,
    Text.class,
    Text.class,
    Text.class,
    true,
    Conf4);
```

---

---

**NOTE:**

```
the out-put Type of  key-value derive which Mapper and reducer is to be called next so , the output Type of Map1 should me same as Input Type of key-value of Reduce1 AND the output Type of Reduce1 should me same as Input Type of key-value of Map2 and 
the output Type of Map2 should me same as Input Type of key-value of Reduce2
```

Comment: Yea, but he wants to share ephemeral data between the two jobs.

Comment: Also I need to process an input file in Map2. So I need an input file from HDFS and Reduce1 output , as inputs for map2.

Comment: I have added another way of doing the same .

Comment: Your code example only uses ChainReducer and no ChainMapper, just a copy paste error. Also please consider answering two times. It makes it easier to comment and vote

Comment: @rretzbach : Edited and posted two ans , Please look,comment and vote other answers too . Ty .

Comment: dont think this works. You can only use 1 reducer in ChainMapper and ChainReducer. The second `ChainReducer.set` call overrides the first

Answer (score 0):

---

### Counters to slove the problem

---

*You can use a counter in Job1,Reduce1 to get the value from Job1 which will be then passed to Job2 .Here is sample code for the flow thing which need to be coded  .*

***1.Sample code to set value using counter***

```
    Reducer()
{
public static enum COUNTER {
  INTVALUE
};

Reduce()
{
// Old API
reporter.incrCounter(COUNTER .INTVALUE, 1);

//NEW API
context.getCounter(COUNTER .INTVALUE).increment(1);

}

}
```

---

---

***2.Getting the set counter from job1 and then setting it to the JonConf of Job2 Where mapper can get the same value .***

---

```
main()
{
// .....
jobclient1.submit(job1);
RunningJob job = JobClient1.runJob(conf);  // blocks until job completes
Counters c = job.getCounters();
int value= c.getCounter(COUNTER .INTVALUE);

// Now set the value in Job2 
Job job2 = new JobConf(conf);
job2.setInt("name", value);
}
```

---

---

***3.Map2 Getting the value from Job1 counter->Jobconf2***

---

```
    mapper()
 {
    int value;

    @Override
    public void configure(JobConf job) {

        value=job.getInt("name", 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void map(Text key, Text value,
            OutputCollector<LongWritable, Text> output, Reporter arg3)
            throws IOException {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
----------
```

### another ans

---

***Save the output from Reduce1 to flatfile(hdfs)
read that file while setting driver(Job) in 2nd job . then set the variable in context.***

---

```
//read reducer output from file . and set it @name variable 
Configuration conf = getConf();
Job job = new JobConf(conf);
conf.setInt("name", 0000);
```

*In mapper(map2)*

```
    mapper()
{
int value;

        @Override
        public void configure(JobConf job) {

            value=job.getInt("name", 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void map(Text key, Text value,
                OutputCollector<LongWritable, Text> output, Reporter arg3)
                throws IOException {


        }
}
```

---